# How to convert a dictionary into a list of tuples without dict functions? [PYTHON]

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

For example I have a dictionary:

```
d = {'a':2,'b':3,'c':4}
```

and I want to convert to this to a list of tuples, like:

```
tList = [('a',2),('b',3),('c',4)]
```

But all of this without using dictionary functions as (`d.items(), d.keys(), d.values(), d.iteritems())`, in Python.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: This is a strange question! Is d[key] legal?

Comment: Why the artificial constraint?

Comment: @chepner what do you want to say with artificial constraint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do it:

```
d = {'a':2,'b':3,'c':4}
tList = [(key, d[key]) for key in d]
```

Comment: @Denziloe `d[key]` is essentially `d.__getitem__(key)` so it depends how pedantic one wants to be, but then most likely any interaction with the dictionary will involve some of the "magic" methods...

Comment: Exactly. All of these things are functions under the hood, so the request for an approach that "doesn't use functions" is pretty incoherent and strange.

Comment: when I said functions the ones I was talking about were the functions that interact "directly" with the dictionary. @Denziloe

Comment: I don't know what that means. Does d.__getitem__ not "interact directly with the dictionary"? And why is this important to you?

Comment: @py_9 my pleasure... :)